# Progress bar is not animating

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, mobile-application

I am trying to get the progress bar to fade out in 3 seconds, but it does not work.

```
// Animate progress bar.
    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView1);
    ObjectAnimator animato = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressBar1, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.0f);
    animato.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animato.setDuration(3000);
    animato.start();
```

Layout (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView1"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:alpha="0.9"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And last, what I meant with "working" is that the progress bar does not fade off.

Comment: Your code looks fine so far, please post your ProgressBar xml , and explain in detail what "it does not work" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AlphaAnimation instead ObjectAnimator >>>

```
AlphaAnimation fade = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);  // from 1 to 0 transparancy 
fade.setDuration(1000);
fade.setFillAfter(true)  //Keeps ProgressBar at 0 opacity after animation
myProgressBar.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
```

Hope it Works :)

BTW you haven't assigned id to your progress bar,
assign ID to your progress bar

then declare a variable named as myProgressBar

then initialize it with corresponding id of your progressbar.

Comment: Sorry, but it crashes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast your ImageView to a ProgressBar with this line :

```
progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView1);
```

R.id.mainImageView1 is assigned to your ImageView in your xml.

Assign an id to your ProgressBar in your xml :

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
     android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
/>
```

and then

```
progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```